# How to read package.json version in TFS build

Tags: json, powershell, tfs, asp.net-core

i'm using TFS 2017 for CI, I wan't to get version stored in package.json file of my .net core project, i tried this powershell script:

```
$SemverVersion = (Get-Content -Raw -Path Path/package.json | ConvertFrom-Json).version
```

I get this error in logs:

```
Get-Content : Impossible de trouver un paramètre positionnel acceptant l'argument «
Le processus s'est achevé avec le code de sortie 0. 1 erreur(s) écrite(s) dans le flux d'erreurs.
```

Is there any other way or tool to read package.json version in TFS Build?

Comment: What version of PowerShell is running? I believe this may be an issue with the `-raw` parameter which wasn't added until PowerShell 3

Comment: im using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/powershell)  Task in TFS 2017

Comment: Can you add `$psversiontable.psversion` to the task and see what version it is running with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BenH, this powerShell works well:

```
(Get-Childitem -Path .\ -Include *package.json* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\wwwroot\*"} | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\no
de_modules\*"}| Where {$_.FullName -like "*\release\*"} | Select-Object -First 1).fullName
>>> $version = (Get-Content $path) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty "version"
>>> Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable SemverVersion=$version;]$version")
```

First i read the path and store it in `$path` varible, then use this variable as  parameter in Get-Content to read version and store it `$version`, finally i set `$version` in `SemverVersion` env variable, 
is there any suggestion to improve this reponse ?

Answer (score 1):

@BenH is correct. Please check [this website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-3.0):

> Raw is a dynamic parameter that the FileSystem provider adds to the
>   Get-Content cmdlet. This parameter works only in file system drives.
>
> This parameter is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

Please install a newer version of Powershell **on the build agent machine**, and restart build agent service, to have another try.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as non one liner:

```
$jsonFile = Get-Content "package.json"
$jsonObj = $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$versionPrefix = $jsonObj.version
```